# Close modal and open new modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a script that shows my login modal on page load. I have a button that opens the register modal and closes the login modal if clicked.

Here is the script I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#loginmodal').modal('show')
});

$(".hidelogopenreg").click( function()
         {
            $('#loginmodal').modal('hide')
            $('#registermodal').modal('show')
         }
 );
```

Even though the works correctly, I fear it's using bad practices as I have little JavaScript knowledge and don't want to have to resolve problems further down the line.

Is this correct and efficient or is there a better way of writing this?

Another problem I had is that hiding a modal causes the body to shift to the right on close, to fix this I added:

```
body {
padding-right:0px !important;
margin-right:0px !important;
}
```

Could this also cause problems for me?

Comment: You're not allowed to make edits to your post that would invalidate existing answers.

Comment: I am not allowed to add additional information?

Comment: Not if it makes the existing answers invalid.  It looked to me like you'd copied code from the answer you'd already received.

Comment: Oh sorry, i changed it slightly and asked if it was okay but i forgot this is codereview and not stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could this also cause problems for me?

As with most CSS questions, the answer is **maybe**. It really depends on the rest of your CSS. Personally, I try to stay away from `!important` but I can certainly understand your usage. As long as it isn't causing additional issues, I don't see a problem with it.

> Is this correct and efficient or is there a better way of writing this?

I would recommend wrapping your code in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) so as not to pollute the global scope and give yourself a "safe" private scope.  This also allows you to use `$` for `jQuery` with no conflicts:

```
(function( $ ) {
  //code here 
})( jQuery );
```

Next, if you see where you use the same jQuery selection more than once, you should just go ahead and cache it:

```
var logModal = $('#loginmodal');
```

I would also recommend that you use K&R style braces instead of Allman style.  This can help [prevent issues you might encounter](http://encosia.com/in-javascript-curly-brace-placement-matters-an-example/) with JS.

```
$(".hidelogopenreg").click( function() {  // opening on same line K&R style
  $('#loginmodal').modal('hide')
  $('#registermodal').modal('show')
}
```

Lastly, you need to end your lines of code with a semicolon. You can get away with this in some situations but can cause issues later on. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717949/when-should-i-use-a-semicolon-after-curly-braces).

```
  $('#loginmodal').modal('hide');  //end of line
  $('#registermodal').modal('show');  //end of line
```

Here is the code with these changes:

```
(function( $ ) {

  var $logModal = $('#loginmodal');
  var $regModal = $('#registermodal');
  var $hideLogin = $(".hidelogopenreg");

  function swapModals() {
    $logModal.modal('hide');
    $regModal.modal('show');
  }

  $(document).ready( function() {
    $logModal.modal( 'show');
    $hideLogin.on( 'click', swapModals );
  });

})( jQuery );
```

Hope that helps.  Let me know if you have questions, comments or need clarification.

Comment: I edited my post to show my implementation. Would this work okay?

Comment: Not sure what the correct way to do a follow up on CR.  How about just create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Oh wait sorry, i forgot this is codereview and not stackoverflow. My bad.